# Link to app from within xcode

Tags: url, itunes

Need button to link to other app in the app store.  I use this...

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] 
  openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@“http://www.google.com"]];
```

it works fine in safari.  From what I read if you want to link to the itunes store directly you use: `itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=409954448`

Whenever I do that it says invalid url.  Maybe its because the app store isn’t available in the simulator?  and it will only work on a device?  Is there any way to test these links in the simulator?

I’m using http://itunes.apple.com/linkmaker/ to get the link to the app.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have answered your own question here:

> Whenever I do that it says invalid url. Maybe its because the app
>   store isn’t available in the simulator? and it will only work on a
>   device?

iOS Simulator doesn't have AppStore/iTunes and therefore can't open AppStore/iTunes links. But the way you do it is correct and should work without issues.